# error when posting to mysql from android

Tags: java, android, mysql

im new to android programming, iv been trying to connect to a remote server and post the data into a mysql database, my code runs fine but when i click on the button to post into database, the app crashes and gives the error "unfortunately the app has stopped working", but when i check the db, the data has been inserted.
can someone please look at the code and tell me why the app is crashing and probably rectify it.

my xml code

```
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input Name -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <!-- Price Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input Price -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

    <!-- Description Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input description -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:lines="4"
        android:gravity="top"/>

    <!-- Button Create Product -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnCreateProduct"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Product"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

my java file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewProduct extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;


    private static String url_create_product =    "http:////bsa.co.ke/androidconnect/create_product.php";   

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_product);

       // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProduct.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
       }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Toast.makeText(NewProduct.this,
                            "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();


                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: java for sure, david add your log to see which error you are receiving.

Comment: but this finish on success is closing that activity and on post execute you have pDialog.dismiss(), it seems like you have an error there. Trying to close progress dialog that is not there in memory because you already finished.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your *Toast* line.

AyncTask creates a thread, and you are trying to call Toast from that thread. But, internally when Toast is called it in turn calls another thread which is a UI thread. You can not call an UI thread from a background thread. 
I sugges you moving that Toast to other part (like postExecute) but if you really want it where it is you can do it with [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
It would look like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

    Toast.makeText(NewProduct.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```